# Bluetooth LE Suported app in PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, bluetooth

I am using "randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle" plugin in PhoneGap/Cordova App to create a Bluetooth application. I am using a simple example which is given on [GitHub page](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle) of the plugin. but I am not getting any device listed but getting a message `Scanning for devices (will continue to scan until you select a device)...`

Below is the Code I am using

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  function onDeviceReady() {
      bluetoothle.initialize({
          request: true,
          statusReceiver: false
      }, initializeSuccess, handleError);
  }

  function initializeSuccess(result) {

      if (result.status === "enabled") {

          log("Bluetooth is enabled.");
          log(result);
      } else {

          document.getElementById("start-scan").disabled = true;

          log("Bluetooth is not enabled:", "status");
          log(result, "status");
      }
  }

  function handleError(error) {

      var msg;

      if (error.error && error.message) {

          var errorItems = [];

          if (error.service) {

              errorItems.push("service: " + (uuids[error.service] || error.service));
          }

          if (error.characteristic) {

              errorItems.push("characteristic: " + (uuids[error.characteristic] || error.characteristic));
          }

          msg = "Error on " + error.error + ": " + error.message + (errorItems.length && (" (" + errorItems.join(", ") + ")"));
      } else {

          msg = error;
      }

      log(msg, "error");

      if (error.error === "read" && error.service && error.characteristic) {

          reportValue(error.service, error.characteristic, "Error: " + error.message);
      }
  }
  var foundDevices = [];

  function startScan() {

      log("Starting scan for devices...", "status");

    

      document.getElementById("devices").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("services").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";

      if (window.cordova.platformId === "windows") {

          bluetoothle.retrieveConnected(retrieveConnectedSuccess, handleError, {});
      } else {

          bluetoothle.startScan(startScanSuccess, handleError, {
              services: []
          });
      }
  }

  function startScanSuccess(result) {
      log("startScanSuccess(" + result.status + ")");

      if (result.status === "scanStarted") {
          log("Scanning for devices (will continue to scan until you select a device)...", "status");
      } else if (result.status === "scanResult") {

          if (!foundDevices.some(function (device) {

                  return device.address === result.address;

              })) {

              log('FOUND DEVICE:');
              log(result);
              foundDevices.push(result);
              addDevice(result.name, result.address);
          }
      }
  }

  function retrieveConnectedSuccess(result) {

      log("retrieveConnectedSuccess()");
      log(result);

      result.forEach(function (device) {

        addDevice(device.name, device.address);

      });
  }

  function addDevice(name, address) {

      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.style.width = "100%";
      button.style.padding = "10px";
      button.style.fontSize = "16px";
      button.textContent = name + ": " + address;

      button.addEventListener("click", function () {

          document.getElementById("services").innerHTML = "";
          connect(address);
      });

      document.getElementById("devices").appendChild(button);
  }

  function log(msg, level) {

      level = level || "log";

      if (typeof msg === "object") {

          msg = JSON.stringify(msg, null, "  ");
      }

      console.log(msg);

      if (level === "status" || level === "error") {

          var msgDiv = document.createElement("div");
          msgDiv.textContent = msg;

          if (level === "error") {

              msgDiv.style.color = "red";
          }

          msgDiv.style.padding = "5px 0";
          msgDiv.style.borderBottom = "rgb(192,192,192) solid 1px";
          document.getElementById("output").appendChild(msgDiv);
      }
  }
```

This is my first Bluetooth LE Project in Cordova. Please help me and suggest any other plugin better than this with good documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing your app on Android 6+ you need to request permission first in order to use the Bluetooth functionality of the device. Otherwise your app will silently fail and you won't see any devices discovered. You can use the built-in method of the Bluetooth LE plugin for this

```
bluetoothle.requestPermission().then(success, fail)
```

Or you can add [cordova-plugin-android-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions), should you need to request other permissions as well.